# Paypal error 10413

Tags: api, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-nvp

I am working with the paypal express checkout API and am having issues.

I have a request like so:

```
METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
...
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=Individual%20Gross%20&%20Net
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=65.00
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_QTY0=1
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=70.26
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_TAXAMT=5.26
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_ITEMAMT=65.00
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_PAYMENTACTION=Sale
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=USD
```

I have reviewed this many times and see no error in the math, yet this is what paypal sends me.

```
TIMESTAMP : 2017-03-22T01:41:05Z
CORRELATION ID : e22e8009c7018
ACK : Failure
VERSION : 88.0
BUILD : 31129382
L_SEVERITYCODE0 : Error
Error Code : 10413
Transaction refused because of an invalid argument. See additional error messages for details.
The totals of the cart item amounts do not match order amounts.
```

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10191209/paypal-api-the-totals-of-the-cart-item-amounts-do-not-match-order-amounts

Comment: Thank you for that. However, I found that PayPal responded this way because I did not include `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0` . After including that field, it was accepted. I must say that the error message sent to me lead to me to the wrong issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that PayPal responded this way because I did not include `L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0` . After including that field, it was accepted. I must say that the error message sent to me lead to me to the wrong issue